# placing Semaphore issue in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i've implemented a client side which sends random numbers to the server, wait for a replay from the server (let's say the server also sends some random value).
the client can't send another request before he gets an answer from the server.

here's my code:

```
private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP;
    private Socket connection;
    private String clientName;
    private String queryNum;
    Semaphore waitForReplay ;

//constructor
    public Client(String host,String clientName){
        serverIP = host;
        waitForReplay = new Semaphore(1, true);
        this.clientName = clientName;
        startRunning();
    }



public void startRunning(){
        try{
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            whileChatting();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
        }.start();

            sendMsgToChat();
        }catch(EOFException eofException){
            showMessage("\n Client terminated the connection");
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            closeConnection();
        }
    }


//connect to server
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
        showMessage("Connection Established! Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    //set up streams
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n The streams are now set up! \n");
    }
//receiving msgs
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        do{
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\nClient"+clientName+": got replay " + message+ " for query " +queryNum);

            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                showMessage("Unknown data received!");
            }
            finally{
                waitForReplay.release();
            }
        }while(true);   
    }



//sending msgs
    private void sendMsgToChat(){
        while(true){

            try {
                waitForReplay.acquire();


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//sends some random num, casting int number from array to string
            sendMessage(queryNum =some random number..);
        }
    }
```

for a reason i can't find out, the waitForRepaly Semaphore dont do his job, and there's scenarios where the client sends few messages in a row, and not waiting for reply from the server .
can you help me find the bug in my code?

Comment: REPLY, IT'S REPY ! Not "replay" ... That's another thing...

Comment: @UDKOX please keep in mind that english is not the first language for everyone arond here. Also, some younger folks (i.e. 1st semster students) may be here as well, so please be a little more forgiving with regards to those kinds of mistake.

Comment: @UDKOX you misspelled "reply" and "repaly".

Comment: @Turing85 It was supposed to sound funny, not angry. Greeting from Darmstadt.

Comment: Can you post the output of your code?

Comment: @shmosel I did not write "repaly".

Comment: @shmosel I'm lost right now, what are you talking about ?

Comment: okay, this gets spammy and the question does not receive the attention it needs </offtopic>. There seems to be something fishy. Following the control flow, you seem to `release()` the semaphore before `acquire()`. In my opinion, you must first send the message (i.e. call `sendMsgToChat()` and then call `whileChatting()`. But this does not explain the described behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, seeing the output of the syso I feel like will pretty quickly resolve this issue.  Again OP, if you can, please post the output of an example run of this.

Comment: @ironcache the post you deleted behaved well, but now for some reason the server sometimes reply with few comments also, im gonna look on my server side now.

Comment: @gilleibovitz Do you mean the server sends a few messages consecutively?  Because right now you don't have any control over that.  For that, you could consider two semaphores.  Have a "client" semaphore (initialized with 1 license), and a "server" semaphore (initialized with 0 licenses).  When the client attempts to send a message, it acquires the client semaphore, sends the message, and releases the server semaphore.  When the server attempts to send a response, it acquires the server semaphore, sends the response, and then releases the client semaphore.  This will ensure 1:1 messaging.

Comment: @ironcache that's what i've done to solve this problem  but let's say there's 3000 clients, holding 3000 semaphores in the server seems pretty consuming to me, isn't it?

Comment: It's two semaphores per, so 3000 clients would mean 6000 semaphores.  Semaphores are very cheap objects, and I don't think it's a janky prospect.  That said, semaphores are a pretty low-level concept, and, if this is not academic in nature, there may be alternative processes or libraries which are more tailored to your solution.

Comment: But honestly I wouldn't worry about the cost of 2 Semaphores in a client over 1.

Comment: When I said "client" and "server" semaphore above, I meant have 2 semaphores on the client side, one for acquiring the license to send data out from the client, and one to acquire the license to receive data from the server (right now you only have the prior).  This will ensure 1:1 messaging (though, it does not ensure that your server sends responses correctly without spamming other content; if that's occurring, then you need to fix the server side code).

Comment: @ironcache yeah, my server side seems to spam too so i should look into the server now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\nClient"+clientName+": got replay " + message+ " for query " +queryNum);

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            showMessage("Unknown data received!");
        }
        finally{
            waitForReplay.release();
        }
    }while(true);
```

Each semaphore release adds 1 available license.  You could potentially be adding licenses when they already exist.

Fix by only releasing the semaphore if there are no licenses available:

```
finally{
    if (!waitForReplay.tryAcquire()) {
        waitForReplay.release();
    }
}
```